# Putting some values into the fields before the first submission

Tags: codeigniter

CI form_validation is working perfectly... but how can I put some values into the fields before the first submission? (edit page)

Comment: Having an edit page means you already submitted the form once when you inserted the values, which is AFTER the first submission. Could you clarify your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the values via using the model, etc.

The form helper can help you with the values. for example:

```
//Controller
$data['user'] = $this->user_model->get_user($id);
$this->load->view('yourview', $data);

 // View
<input type='Text' name='username' value='<?php echo set_value('name', $user->name);?>'>
```